# C# Azure Upload Files to "File Storage Service" - not Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure

I have a requirement to upload files to *Azure File Storage* service C#, (not Blob Storage), I searched a lot but I don't find how, only find info of how to do it for Blob Storage, It seems that it's not supported or I'm searching bad.

I'm able to get until here, but there's no `UploadFromStream()` method like in blob

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\...\file.txt");
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShareReference"]);
CloudFileDirectory root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
CloudFileDirectory dir = root.GetDirectoryReference("TESTDIR");

using (FileStream fs = file.OpenRead())
{
    // what should I do here
}
```

Is it possible to upload the file like this?
In which case what am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to first create a `CloudFile` instance to the file that you want to create from your `CloudFileDirectory` instance. Once you have the reference, you can upload it multiple ways, including the `CloudFile.UploadFromStream()` method.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\...\file.txt");
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShareReference"]);
CloudFileDirectory root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
CloudFileDirectory dir = root.GetDirectoryReference("TESTDIR");

var cloudFile = dir.GetFileReference("myfile.txt");

using (FileStream fs = file.OpenRead())
{
    cloudFile.UploadFromStream(fs);
}
```

Comment: What is a ShareReference. i couldnt find it in any documents. it just has storage name and key in documentation

Comment: This will help to upload small files only.Anybody know how to upload large files (approx:500MB) to fileshare?